# Can't set constant property in xml

Tags: java, xml, annotations

In my java 8 project:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Network {
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    private NetworkSupportedFeaturesSection networkSupportedFeaturesSection;

}
```

As result in xml I get smt like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
         <return>
            <networkSupportedFeaturesSection>
               <some>ENABLE</sme>
            <networkSupportedFeaturesSection>
         </return>
      </ns2:getNetworkResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As you can see it generate in xml property depend on varible name in java file.

**networkSupportedFeaturesSection**

But I want to **set independent solution**. Never mind what variable name is in class. In the xml **must be always smt like this**:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
         <return>
            <mySpecifiName>
               <some>ENABLE</sme>
            <mySpecifiName>
         </return>
      </ns2:getNetworkResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This annotation `@XmlValue("mySpecifiName")`   not help